# Need solution to integrate Grafana with Azure data lake

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-data-lake

I want to integrate Azure data lake storage with Grafana for visualization of time series data. I need to know what all the tools I can use to make it possible.

I used ADF to extract data from csv files stored in data lake and move to a table in Azure data explorer. After that, I used Azure data explorer plugin in grafana to visualize the same. It worked fine. But I need to know is there any other approach which may be better or cost-effective.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating Grafana with Azure Data Lake is the best option when compared to others because the other options include data movements using ADF and additional cost for Azure SQL Datawarehouse along with the cost of PowerBI.

**Reason:**

Grafana is a leading open source software designed for visualizing time series analytics. It is an analytics and metrics platform that enables you to query and visualize data and create and share dashboards based on those visualizations. Combining Grafana’s beautiful visualizations with Azure Data Explorer’s snappy ad hoc queries over massive amounts of data, creates impressive usage potential.

The Grafana and Azure Data Explorer teams have created a dedicated plugin which enables you to connect to and visualize data from Azure Data Explorer using its intuitive and powerful Kusto Query Language. In just a few minutes, you can unlock the potential of your data and create your first Grafana dashboard with Azure Data Explorer.

For more details on visualizing data from Azure Data Explorer in Grafana please visit our documentation, “[Visualize data from Azure Data Explorer in Grafana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/grafana)”.

**Other options:**

**For Azure Data Lake Gen1:**

You can use a mix of services to create visual representations of data stored in Data Lake Storage Gen1.

[image]

You can start by using [Azure Data Factory to move data from Data Lake Storage Gen1 to Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview).

After that, you can [integrate Power BI with Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-visualize-with-power-bi) to create visual representation of the data.

**For Azure Data Lake Gen2:**

You can use a mix of services to create visual representations of data stored in Data Lake Storage Gen2.

[image]

You can start by using [Azure Data Factory to move data from Data Lake Storage Gen2 to Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview).

After that, you can [integrate Power BI with Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-visualize-with-power-bi) to create visual representation of the data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

They just released a new guide.  This is for Grafana 5.3

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/grafana

you are able to test this by running Grafana in a Docker container (or for real, if you want).  I followed the guide, and it is working almost exactly as expected.  The only issue I am having is Grafana is concatenating the column name and the data in the column, making reading and formatting tricky.